# Placing two images next to text

Tags: html, css

My site: [www.pkgeek.com](http://www.pkgeek.com)

Just scroll down to the footer and you will see Powered by and on the next line you will see two icons (Blogger icon and namecheap icon). I want these icons to be displayed next to Powered by: (Not on the next line).

My HTML Code for these icons and the footer Powered by links:

```
  Powered By: <div class="div123">
<a href="#" title="Hosted on Google Blogger" class="blogger"></a>
<a href="#" title="Subdomains from NameCheap" class="namecheap"></a>
</div></div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.div123 {

    }
    .blogger {
    background:url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-EcPHtL7JRak/Uz8VLVBfGCI/AAAAAAAAAoc/WOHpaJy7hxg/s1600/blogger.png');
    background-position:0 0;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    }

    .blogger:hover {
    background-position:0 25px;

    }

    .namecheap {
    background:url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GOvEY9lWKkU/Uz8VNmQMq5I/AAAAAAAAAok/RRLbRx_EDYc/s1600/Namecheap.png');
    background-position:0 0;
    width:35px;
    height:20px;
    display:inline-block;


    }

    .namecheap:hover {
    background-position:0 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Give a proper width to `div.poweredbylinks` like `150px` then do `.div123 {float:right;}`

Comment: @BatuZet I do what you said, But now the powered by is a little bit up. Do i need to set a height and then line-height?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is entirely reliant on a link that is now dead.

Comment: (yesterday it would not respond at all, today I get a warning symbol and a Chinese error, presumably a 404 or site not found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the width for the div poweredbylinks and add the properties: `.poweredbylinks{ vertical-align:top; line-height:25px; }` and for the div .div123 remove the width, float and the height, and set his styles to: `.div123{ display:inline-block; }`

Comment: It's looking good, But If it can come a little bit more down? (Both Powered by and images) so there will be less gap between Copyright and Powered by

Comment: `.dmcafooter{ float:right; /* remove the left porperty */}` and move this div inside the `.poweredbylinks` div. Then remove the html `br` that's before the copyright text.  Later edit: also your footer is somehow left aligned, remove the `margin-left` property from the div `.copyrightstheme` and add this rule: `margin:0 auto` to center it with the rest of content.

Comment: It is looking good, Just the dmca is up ( I will fix that myself ^_^ ). BTW I've used margin-left:88px; To center the footer. I know that trick margin:0 auto; (Trick used for centering) but i tried it, It didn't worked xD :D

Thank you :D

Comment: Try to do the updates in chrome dev tools. Then add them in your css file, later after you've checked that everything is alright. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give the following css property `float:left` to the **two pictures and the text. Edit the html to this and it works:

```
<div style="float:left;">  Powered By:</div> <div class="div123">
<a href="#" title="Hosted on Google Blogger" class="blogger" style="float:left;"></a>
<a href="#" title="Subdomains from NameCheap" class="namecheap" style="float:left;"></a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Hmm that works but puts a gap... @lucian works perfect!
Thank you :))

Comment: @OmerIqbal you could add a margin property to change this

Comment: Hmmm yeah but If i use it my other things (DMCA) will be not set :)

Thank you ;) I appreciate your help! :) Thank you so much ;)

Comment: @OmerIqbal sorry I couldn't help you. kind regards Ip address

Comment: Np :)) Your answer was also good and it just sets the Blogger and NC icon :))

Answer (score 0):

Replace div by this:

```
<div class="poweredbylinks">
<div style="float:left">Powered By:</div> <div class="div123">
<i class="blogger"></i>
<i class="namecheap"></i>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm that works but puts a gap... @lucian works perfect!
Thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `style=" display: inline; "` to your divs like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4bME/)